# Estimation of regression with autocorrelated errors

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, multiple-regression, autocorrelation

In a book it is written that,

In regression work we typically assume that the observational errors are pairwise uncorrelated. But in most time series data , the successive residuals have tendency to correlated with themselves.If we find autocorrelated  errors, we need to modify the regression procedure to remove the effect of autocorrelated  errors. Typically this is done by an appropriate transformation of the variables used in the regression estimation procedure.

Consider a multiple regression model with autocorrelated  errors
$$Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1X_{1t}+\beta_2X_{2t}\ldots+\beta_pX_{pt}+\epsilon_t\ldots(1)$$

and the same regression model at time ${t-1}$ is
$$Y_{t-1}=\beta_0+\beta_1X_{1,{t-1}}+\beta_2X_{2,{t-1}}\ldots+\beta_pX_{p,{t-1}}+\epsilon_{t-1}\ldots(2)$$

Multiplying both sides of this equation by correlation coefficient $\rho$,the correlation between adjacent errors gives
$$\rho Y_{t-1}=\rho \beta_0+\rho \beta_1X_{1,{t-1}}+\rho \beta_2X_{2,{t-1}}\ldots+\rho \beta_pX_{p,{t-1}}+\rho \epsilon_{t-1}$$

Then we subtract this equation from the first  equation  to obtain
$Y_t-\rho Y_{t-1}=\beta_0(1-\rho)+\beta_1(X_{1t}-\rho X_{1,{t-1}})+\beta_2(X_{2t}-\rho X_{2,{t-1}})\ldots+\beta_p(X_{pt}-\rho X_{p,{t-1}})+u_t\ldots(3)$

where $u_t=\epsilon_t-\rho \epsilon_{t-1}$ has uniform variance and is not autocorrelated.

#### $\bullet$ My first question is : Why do they multiply $\rho $ in model $(2)$? Why not in model $(1)$?

#### $\bullet$ My second  question is :Are the  data of independent variable $X$ in model$(1)$ same as the  data of independent variable $X$ in model $(2)$ ? If this data depends on time, then they seem to be not equal data. If so then my parameters $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots\beta_p$ are not same for  the model $(1)$ and $(2)$. Then how can i write model $(3)$? More specifically, how can i take $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots\beta_p$ as common factor ?

#### $\bullet$ My last question is : how does $u_t=\epsilon_t-\rho \epsilon_{t-1}$ have  uniform variance and why is not autocorrelated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1) This is done so that you will get representation in eq. (3).

2) Beta-parameters are time invariant and only values of X variables will be different since they are at different lags. Then you can arrange eq. (1) and (2) in form of (3).

3) Usually $\epsilon_{t}=\rho \epsilon_{t-1}+u_{t}$ where $u_{t}\sim iid(0,\sigma_u)$ which means that $u_{t}$ is not autocorrelated and has uniform variance.

Transformation in eq. (3) is known as Cochrane-Orcutt transformation and with handling of initial values it is known as Prais-Winsten transformation.

Comment: (2)If The first and second model were based on sample,say,$\hat Y_t=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1X_{1t}+\hat\beta_2X_{2t}\ldots+\hat\beta_pX_{pt}+e_t \ldots(1)$, then estimated beta parameters depends on $X$'s. So if the case is of `sample` i can't take those estimated beta parameters  as common factors.Isn't it?

Comment: @Leaf your model is theoretical one, we assume that our model correctly represents reality. This means that algebraic manipulation which produces eq. (3) is valid one if residual autocorrelation process is AR(1) as I put in my answer. Now if you want to really use this result in empirical work you must be able to somehow estimate rho parameters value and use it in GLS estimation which produces autocorrelation free model.