# Select statistical test for 2 mutually exclusive conditions on one time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance

I'm new to time series data, and I want to answer a question like:
"On days when I eat a banana, is my average blood sugar level higher?"

That means, I have a time series where I have a bunch of blood sugar levels sampled every day, from which I can calculate a daily average. Let's say I have this data for 60 consecutive days.

I also have the information on whether I ate a banana or not for each day during the 60-day period.

Should I use a simple Students t test (assuming normal distribution), or would that be inappropriate as there may be a seasonal variation in my blood glucose levels as this is happening along a time line?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a regression with autocorrelated errors. Let the response variable be *blood sugar level*, let the *banana* variable be a binary predictor. Or you could lag *blood sugar level*.

There are multiple posts here on regression with autocorrelated errors, some

- [Estimation of regression with autocorrelated errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109308/estimation-of-regression-with-autocorrelated-errors)
- [OLS vs. Regression with ARMA errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324517/ols-vs-regression-with-arma-errors)
- [Time Series Regression: serially correlated errors vs autocorrelation of residuals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/time-series-regression-serially-correlated-errors-vs-autocorrelation-of-residua)